# Python3 : jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

```
{% for title, link in bball_breakdown_posts.iteritems() %}
```

jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'dict object' has no attribute 'iteritems'
I changed .iteritems() to .items i got the same error`

```
{% for title, link in bball_breakdown_posts.items() %}
```

Comment: If it is duplicate, where is original post? @juanpa.arrivillaga

Comment: it is linked at the top immediately below the title.

Comment: I read that before and even I have mentioned that solution didn't fix my problem.

Comment: You need to change the title, and should also remove your old code.

Comment: I changed it. So now it will not come under duplicate